# Problema con mostrar datos de múltiples tablas (Laravel) (Eloquent)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, join

Estoy realizando un Selector, para poder filtrar la búsqueda de pisos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cosa es que en esa búsqueda se interactua con dos bases de datos:

1. pisos, tiene modelo creado ya, y tiene un método con la tabla "oficinas" **belongsTo**
2. oficinas, tiene también el modelo ya creado, y un método hacía "pisos" **hasMany**

Las propiedades de "compra" y "piso" son características dentro de la tabla de pisos, y el tercer campo "Delicias" es el nombre de la oficina.

El problema es que no consigo hacer un join con Eloquent para que me devuelva los pisos que sean de tipo "compra", el tipo de inmueble sea "piso", y sea de la oficina "delicicias" otra tabla.

*En la base de datos pisos tiene un campo llamado oficina_id dónde se enlaza con la oficina que le corresponde.*

**Controlador:**

```
    // Esto recoge el tipo de inmueble ( casa , piso, aparatmento... y abajo recoge si es alquiler o compra.)
    $tipo_inmueble = $request->input('tipo_propiedad');
    $venta_alquiler = $request->input('venta_alquiler');

    $id_oficina = $request->input('oficina');
    // EL problema es que no consigo filtrarlo aquí..
    $data = Oficina::find($id_oficina)->join('pisos','pisos.oficina_id', '=', 'oficinas.id');
```

Esto no me devuelve los resultados, al hacer un **dd()** me da esto... (Pego imagen por que al pegar el array tan grande no me deja publicar)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**SOLUCION A MI PROBLEMA**

```
    $pisos_filtrados = \DB::table('pisos')
                                ->join('oficinas', 'pisos.oficina_id', '=', 'oficinas.id')
                                ->where('oficinas.id', '=', $id_oficina)
                                ->where('pisos.tipo_propiedad', '=', $tipo_propiedad)
                                ->where('pisos.modalidad', '=', $modalidad)->get();
```

Comment: Al final de tu consulta de manera inicial falta un get

Comment: Lo he solucionado, si faltaba el GET pero de todas formas lo he hecho sin eloquent, me ha sido más facil

Comment: En estos casos lo recomendable es publicar la solución y así la pregunta no queda abandonada

Comment: La solución no va en la pregunta si no en la zona de respuestas, edita y corrige

Comment: Gracias @BetaM, ya está

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**La solución ha sido hacerlo con eloquent y sobretodo poner el metodo get al final..**

```
$pisos_filtrados = Oficina::find($id_oficina)
->join('pisos','pisos.oficina_id', '=', 'oficinas.id')
->get();
```

Comment: Lo hice tambien con query builder, poniendo el get que faltaba, pero al hacer loop los datos no me los devolvía bien..